# Combinatorial problem related to Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, jordan-normal-form

Assume that $n\times n$ real matrix $A$ is in Jordan canonical form. Also, assume that $A$ has $k$ distinct positive real eigenvalues; and that for each eigenvalue it has maximum two Jordan blocks. Using similarity transformation we can shuffle the Jordan blocks of $A$. Let the final $A$ be equal to:

$$\hat{A}=\begin{bmatrix}A_1&0\\0&A_2\end{bmatrix},$$

such that single $A_i$ cannot contain two Jordan block with equal eigenvalues. This is combinatorial problem and among all the variations, I want to obtain the one such that $\det(A_1)$ is as close as possible to $\det(A_2)$.

Examples:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&0\\0&2&1&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \hat{A}=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}, A_1=\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}, A_2=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}5&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&5&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&5&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&2&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&2&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \hat{A}=\begin{bmatrix}5&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&5&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&5&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&2&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}, A_1=\begin{bmatrix}5&1&0\\0&5&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}, A_2=\begin{bmatrix}5&0&0&0\\0&2&1&0\\0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

When $A$ has just couple of eigenvalues I can do the splitting into $A_i$ by hand, but when there are many different eigenvalues computation becomes tricky. Is there a smart way this can be done, is it possible to code such combinatorial problem?

Comment: What kind of eigenvalues are we talking about? At one extreme would be just any complex numbers, at the other would be positive reals. How are you measuring the "closeness" of $\det A_1$ and $\det A_2$? Just the absolute difference $|\det A_1-\det A_2|$? Or, if we're working with positive real eigenvalues, perhaps $|\ln \det A_1/\det A_2|$? (If so, you can turn this into an additive problem.) Even in optimistic cases I'm not sure how much better than brute force we can do. What is the source of this problem?

Comment: I am considering positive real eigenvalues larger than $1$. By "closeness" I mean $|\det A_1-\det A_2|$. I was studying different state-space linear transformations, and got curious whether matrix $A$ can be decomposed to the form in the question, if it can be, then it would mean that each $A_i$ can be controlled by single input and hopefully minimum energy spent.

Comment: Suppose the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_k$ have Jordan blocks with determinants $d_1,d_1',\cdots,d_k,d_k'$ (where $d_i'=1$ when there isn't a second Jordan block). Order them so $d_i\ge d_i'$ and define ratios $r_i=d_i/d_i'\ge1$. Then $|\det A_1-\det A_2|$ is of the form $(\prod_{\ell=1}^kd_\ell')|\prod_{i\in I}r_i-\prod_{j\in J}r_j|$ where $\{I,J\}$ is a partition of $\{1,\cdots,k\}$. So this partitioning problem is the combinatorial translation of the matrix problem.